# Get radio buttons consistant values inside function to update Wordpress userdata

Tags: php, html, wordpress, post, radio-button

I have the following function with an array of variables that handles a profile form. All but one is a typical input, with the exception of `'member-comptency[]'`. It's a select field with several possible values. Right now, the form saves, all the data comes through as expected with the exception of that field which simply returns a number which I assume is the HTML `value`. In looking at it a bit more, the "value" of the element is simply a number also, which might make matters worse.

I've tried in vain several times to modify this in different ways, but only produces a 'no-save' situation, or further non-descrip errors. I understand this field is an array itself, but not sure how to even ask a better question to get myself on track.

### The function

```
function getUMFormData(){
    $id = um_user('ID');
        $names = array(
            'member-company',
            'member-phone',
            'member-website',
            'member-competency[]',
            'member-contact-billing-name'
        );

        foreach( $names as $name )
        update_user_meta( $id, $name, $_POST[$name] );
}
```

### The HTML element

One of several choices

```
<label class="um-field-radio  um-field-half  right ">
  <input type="radio" name="member-competency[]" value="1">

  <span class="um-field-radio-state">
    <i class="um-icon-android-radio-button-off"></i>
  </span>

  <span class="um-field-radio-option">Manufacturer</span>
</label>
```

### The desired outcome

I need to get the word from the last `<span>` element (Manufacturer in the example) to save into the `getUMFormData()` function.

Comment: My first guess is that `member-competency[]` is not a valid meta key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your HTML example, note that the "Manufacturer" radio button has "1" as value.

Now, in your function, the meta key to be used is `'member-competency'` without `[]`.

Then note that `$_POST['member-competency']` will give an array like `array('1')` because of `[]` in `member-comptency[]` attribute name from the input radio button HTML.

If you get `array('1')` from `$_POST['member-competency']` is that the selected radio button is "Manufacturer", and you can set "Manufacturer" as meta value.

So your function will be:

```php
function getUMFormData(){
    $user_id = um_user('ID');

    $fields  = array(
        'member-company',
        'member-phone',
        'member-website',
        'member-competency', // <== Removed "[]"
        'member-contact-billing-name'
    );

    foreach( $fields as $meta_key ) {
        if ( $user_id > 0 && isset($_POST[$meta_key]) ) {
            $meta_value = $_POST[$meta_key];
            // Targeting 'member-competency' field with "Manufacturer" label
            if ( $meta_key === 'member-competency' && is_array($meta_value) && current($meta_value) == '1' ) {
                update_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, __("Manufacturer") );
            } 
            // Other fields
            else {
                update_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, esc_attr($meta_value) );
            }
        }
    }      
}
```

It should work.

---

**Addition:**

In your radio buttons HTML, to copy the label name to the input attribute "value" you can use the following:

```php
add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_footer_custom_script', 10);
function wp_footer_custom_script() {
    ?><script>
    jQuery(function($){
        $('[name^=member-competency]').each(function(){
            $(this).attr('value', $(this).parent().find('span.um-field-radio-option').text());
        });
    });
    </script><?php
}
```

Then your function will change slightly:

```php
function getUMFormData(){
    $user_id = um_user('ID');

    $fields  = array(
        'member-company',
        'member-phone',
        'member-website',
        'member-competency', // <== Removed "[]"
        'member-contact-billing-name'
    );

    foreach( $fields as $meta_key ) {
        if ( $user_id > 0 && isset($_POST[$meta_key]) ) {
            $meta_value = $_POST[$meta_key];
            // Targeting 'member-competency' field with "Manufacturer" label
            if ( $meta_key === 'member-competency' && is_array($meta_value) ) {
                update_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, esc_attr( current($meta_value) ) );
            } 
            // Other fields
            else {
                update_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, esc_attr($meta_value) );
            }
        }
    }      
}
```

It should work and solve your worry.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain. So, in the second 'if' statement, it looks like i'll have to define what each option could be rather than retrieving it as a variable in some fashion?

Comment: Yes. As you have many options, you can add a 2nd foreach, looping through an array of label names, to get the correct one, for example… Or you can use if / elseif. *But maybe you can select multiple options, so it will be more complicated in that case.*

Comment: Again, thank you for your time. I do have to ask for completeness–should I assume theres no way to grab the value and make the association without declaring all options explicitly? My concern would be if the available options change, the function would need to be updated.

Comment: I have added an addition with the required jQuery code to copy the label name to the input attribute "value" in your radio buttons HTML… Try it, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose 'member-competency[]' is not the right way to access an array of values within the post array. You could try to var_dump() or print_r() the $_POST['member-competency']; See if the array is displayed properly.